# I tried to save image in my internal storage the file is saved but it hows damaged

Tags: java, android, image

I pick the image from gallery and tried to save the image in my internal storage.
The file is saved but it looks damaged. It is not showing the image.
Can I know what I have to do now?

Here is image I got:
[image: Here is image I got]

```
    public class ImageUpload extends android.app.Fragment
    {
        ImageView image;
        String img_str;


        Button upload;

        Bitmap finalBitmap;

        private static final int CONTENT_REQUEST=1337;
        private File output=null;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_imageupload,container,false);
            image=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image);
            upload=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.upload);



           /* Bitmap bitmap = image.getDrawingCache();*/
            image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    i.setType("image/*");
                    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(i, "Select Picture"), 1);

                       save Image();
                       }
            });
            image.buildDrawingCache();
           finalBitmap = image.getDrawingCache();

            return v;
        }
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (resultCode == MainActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == 1) {
                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                    System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                    image.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
                    image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

                }
                else if (requestCode == CONTENT_REQUEST) {
                    if (resultCode == 1337) {
                        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(output), "image/jpeg");
                        startActivity(i);
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }
                }
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
        public String getPath(Uri uri) {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri,
                    projection, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null)
                return null;
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String s = cursor.getString(column_index);
            cursor.close();

            return s;
        }
        public String image() {
            image.buildDrawingCache();
            finalBitmap = image.getDrawingCache();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
            byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
            System.out.println("byte array:" + image);

            img_str = Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), img_str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println("string:" + img_str);
            return null;
        }
     private void save Image() {

            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/hello_images");
            myDir.mkdirs();
            Random generator = new Random();
            int n = 10000;
            n = generator.nextInt(n);
            String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
            File file = new File (myDir, fname);
            if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     }`
```

Comment: you want to save image from Imageview to sdcard.. right?

Comment: You have an uri for the picked image. You can use the uri to simple copy the file. Why would you first put the image in an imageview and then execute all kind of manupilations to extract data to put in an image file? Dont understand.

Comment: Ganesh Pokale my problem is i stored image in Internal Storage but the problem is image is not shown.the above blank image is shown.i don't know where the problem is exactly

Comment: greenapps yes i need how to copy the file in internal/external .i saved image in internal.But it blank image(above gave).i have to see image which i pick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in OnActivityResult

```
 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path);
        thumb.setImageBitmap(bmp);
saveImageFile(bmp);
```

Save Bitmap to sdcard Method

```
 public String saveImageFile(Bitmap bitmap) {
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        String filename = getFilename();
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return filename;
    }


  private String getFilename() {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath(), "TestFolder");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        String uriSting = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/"
                + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        return uriSting;
    }
```

Comment: Ganesh Pokale i didn't get Bitmap from drawable i got it from my gallery i would like save this into another location of my phone.

Comment: Thank You Ganesh Pokale but still i got same image in internal memory.if u don't mine can you please send me full source code for this

Comment: which image path we have to take here from drawable right??

Comment: or from internal stoarge

Comment: From internal storage you bind Image to imageview inside onActivityResult   "   selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);  "

Comment: assign this path here   Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
        thumb.setImageBitmap(bmp);
saveImageFile(bmp);

Comment: Thank you Ganesh Pokale.

Comment: Thank You Very Much Dude I Got OutPut

Comment: Great ... .. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the saveImage function even before the `finalBitmap` variable has any value, If you call the below function when you click the `ImageView` with it's drawing cache, It could work ( adjust the path as required).

```
public File WriteBmpToFile(Bitmap bmp) {
        String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                "/.kyc";

        File dir = new File(file_path);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(dir, "kyc_" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");

        FileOutputStream fOut = null;
        try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try {
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return file;
    }
```